# balanced alternating column layout in CSS3

Tags: css

I'm trying create a balanced (2-) column-layout.

The content is not text but blocks and varies in height.
The content should be placed alternatingly left and right, as long as "left" and "right" have (roughly) the same height..

I.e. in this image:
[image]
The space between 1 and 3's shouldn't be there.

Or in this image:
[image]
the 2's should stand alone on the right side and the 1, 3's and 4 should stand on the left side (without space between them).

I tried using "floating `<li>`'s" like this:

HTML:

```
<ol class="context">
    <li class="gruppe">1</li>
    <li class="gruppe">2.0<br />2.1</li>
    <li class="gruppe">3.0<br />3.1</li>    
    <li class="gruppe">4</li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol.context 
{
  border: 1px solid #048;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 8px 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

li.gruppe
{
  background: #048;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  font: bold 32px Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
}
```

(See [attempt 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Nils_a/bMvPQ/) and [attempt 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Nils_a/bMvPQ/1/))

I have also tried to use column's (`column-count: 2; column-fill: auto;`) but this does not fill the columns left-to-right first. (It fills top-to-bottom first.)

Is this even possible without JavaScript?

Comment: No, not without JavaScript (Masonry, Isotope, etc). If you really, really want to get away with CSS only, you'd need to bring in additional server-side code logic in order to precalculate the possible height and prepare the items at the right places (e.g. 1, 3 and 4 on the left side and 2 on the right side in case of example #2).

Comment: You can have a look on facebook how they display the wall. They also use two columns like you are trying to achieve, and they are using "float:left" and "float:right" to move blocks left and right

Comment: Can't you change the HTML? In the layout you are describing there doesn't seem to be a direct optical/logical connection between the items in the left and right column, so why do they have to be in a ordered list? (NB: Avoid `calc`. Browser support is still very limited)

Comment: @RaraituL Yeah, but the two columns on Facebook contain different kinds of blocks. It's not so much an 'alternating column layout' as a 'two totally unrelated columns layout'.

Comment: @RoToRa Change the HTML to what? What alternative HTML would be easier to style in the layout requested? I don't think changing the HTML would help in any way.

Comment: Arg, forget it. I read your post several times, and I just now understood, what you actually want. Sorry, the others are right, you'll need JS for that.

Comment: @Nils: in its current state, the only valid answer to your question is "No" (to *"Is this even possible without JavaScript?"*), hereby making it rhetorical. The bounty makes your question even more confusing, because the question is merely a Yes-No question. I strongly recommend to reformulate your question in such way that constructive answers can be given which really solve your concrete functional requirement. E.g., do you want to perform the job in the server side? Then you really need to tell something more about that part (e.g. the language used, available preconditions/variables, etc).

Comment: @BalusC How do you know it's not possible with pure CSS? I agree that it doesn't *feel* possible to me, and I can't see a way to do it with the tools that CSS offers, but what's your proof? Even if you're right, this is still perfectly possible to answer constructively as it stands; just "No, I don't think this is possible with pure CSS, but here's a succinct and elegant way to it with Javascript..." is a valid, useful answer, and an ideal answer would look at what tools CSS offers that look like they might do the job and explain compellingly why they are, together, inadequate for the task.

Comment: Optimising this layout almost sounds like the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

Comment: @Mark: I will post answer once OP left feedback with necessary information. So far it look like he can't be bothered.

Comment: @BalusC: Agreed, that I did not specify the where/how to solve this. So I'll elaborate: This needs to be done on the client, without server-code. I would prefer a solution in CSS but I'm guessing there's no way (hence the is-it-even-possible-statement). BTW: The bounty was to draw attention (as stated in the reason for the bounty) since the question had no hit's in 2 days.

Comment: Okay, then I can't help you further. Your closest bet is CSS columns (as already answered), but you'll need to live with its pitfalls (browser compatibility, etc). That is, when the JavaScript restriction still stands. Otherwise, it's a piece of cake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say this is not possible without JS. Here is a fiddle I made based on an article from Ben Holland. At least to me looks like what you are after.

http://jsfiddle.net/QWsBJ/2/

HTML:

```
<body onload="setupBlocks();">
  <div class="block">
    <p>***Content***</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>***Content***</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>***Content***</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>***Content***</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>***Content***</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
  position: absolute;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

JS:

```
var colCount = 0;
var colWidth = 0;
var margin = 20;
var blocks = [];

$(function(){
    $(window).resize(setupBlocks);
});

function setupBlocks() {
    colWidth = $('.block').outerWidth();
    colCount = 2
    for(var i=0;i<colCount;i++){
        blocks.push(margin);
    }
    positionBlocks();
}

function positionBlocks() {
    $('.block').each(function(){
        var min = Array.min(blocks);
        var index = $.inArray(min, blocks);
        var leftPos = margin+(index*(colWidth+margin));
        $(this).css({
            'left':leftPos+'px',
            'top':min+'px'
        });
        blocks[index] = min+$(this).outerHeight()+margin;
    }); 
}

Array.min = function(array) {
    return Math.min.apply(Math, array);
};
```

Comment: I share your belief that this isn't possible without Javascript, although my justification for that is simply "I can't think of a way to do this without Javascript." A more concrete argument/proof that this can't be done with pure CSS would be nice, I suppose, although I can't think of one of those, either. Anyway, +1.

Comment: The problem here is to find a solution that would work in every situation. What people suggest here is to make every other float right rather than left. What if it happens to be that the 2nd and the 4th element are much taller than the 1st and 3rd, it could very well be. That would ruin most of these answers. Very curious about this.

Comment: I think that we all agree that Css will not do it, it is not magic, even with flexbox. My belief is that css can only be used as a fall back dispatching <li> lines by lines (float or display) or within column. CSS is not meant to interact with screen & size of boxes but to tell how element should behave at screen among others. Mediaqueries, transition, animation , flexbox, some psudo-class may let you think it is possible, but it is not the case yet :) .

Comment: Though I am still curious about why this is not possible using CSS, this answers not only the question, but also solves my original problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Updated: I believe this is almost impossible to achieve with CSS only. There are many different solutions, but they all require some compromises unless you are willing to use JavaScript or some server-side code.

### Using CSS columns

Here's [an alternate fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abitdodgy/Ng9nY/2/) using reordered blocks. Here's a [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abitdodgy/Ng9nY/) using CSS columns without reordering.

You can use **[CSS colunms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts)**  to change your block flow to vertical unless you alter the order of their output. If you can output odd numbers first, then even numbers, you win.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block1">1</div>
  <div class="block3">3</div>
  <div class="block2">2</div>
  <div class="block6">4</div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    column-count: 2;
    column-width: 100px;
    -moz-column-width: 100px;
    -webkit-column-width: 100px;
    width: 260px;
}
div {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}
.block1 { height: 100px; }
.block2 { height: 130px; }
.block3 { height: 150px; }
.block4 { height: 100px; }
```

This solution is not compatible with IE9 and below.

### Block Height Known

If you do know your block heights you can solve this problem by using **absolute** positioning.

```
block1 {
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; 
  top: 0;
}

block2 {
  height: 110px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; 
  top: 100px; /* The height of the div above it */
}
```

A big drawback is dynamic content; we seldom know block height. So this solution is very limited in its application unless you are willing to calculate the height block height.

### If you are willing to use JS

Use a plugin like Masonry. Both in [vanilla js](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/) or [jQuery flavour](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

### Other Options

This leaves you with the following options that require some compromises.

1. Group your blocks into columns. See [this Fiddle for a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abitdodgy/tdrKa/). This will alter the flow of your blocks to vertical, then horizontal.
2. Use `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;` on your blocks. This will leave some white space below your blocks.
3. Force the height of your blocks, rendering this a non-issue. For blocks with additional content use the `overflow` property to allow in-block scrolling.
4. As others have commented, you could attempt to calculate the height of the blocks on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a mix of flex and float (only tested in Firefox/IE10 and safari 5.1.7 ,  cause to my own opinion, CSS is not your solution)

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/zgAiw

But, in any CSS case you choose, the best is to relay on the mansonry script. 
CSS is not really adapted to this kind of layout. At this time you have many CSS method for layout and basicly: display and float.

You can easily use this together within your html tree structure but this methods are not meant to be mixed. A boxe will be floatting, an inline-level-box or block-level-box and each are suppose to interact in the flow.
Float, breaks a line before itself after a non floatting element or slides down untill it has enough room, that you dispatch right/left via CSS r not.

inline-block moves away from floatting elements and breaks a line if not enough room left, floatting elements among inline-blocks will keep breaking a line before floating.

Column CSS will fill columns with content one by one. see : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/AtazJ

Inline-flex elements seems to work with floatting elements ... but is it suppose to untill it's a validated rule ?

What seems to be wised to me , is to used a javascript for the layout expected and relay on float or display:inline-block + width as a fall back.

Last solution is to think this ahead on your server side and dispatch your items in 2 containers with another appropriate markup if that is possible ( no idea of your real life content dispatched in your `ol li` ).

The CSS for the FLEX test :

```
li.gruppe
{
  background: #048;
  color: white;
  font: bold 32px Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border-bottom:1px solid white;
   border-bottom:1px solid white;
    display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -moz-inline-flex;
  display: -ms-inline-flex;
  display: inline-flex;  
  width:50%;
 }
li:nth-child(even){
  float:right;
  clear:right;
  border-left:1px solid white;
  margin-top:0;
}
```

Comment: excuse my average english , do not hesitate to correct me or question again :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is an interesting solution, but unfortunately it does not solve the problem that was asked for.

The solution I propose here puts subsequent elements into alternating columns, so: 1 -> left, 2 -> right, 3 -> left, 4 -> right, etc.

This is a interesting problem by itself, but not what was asked for.

Thanks to @Nils in the comments for pointing this out.

### Original answer

Here is my attempt with flex!
https://jsfiddle.net/vqLr8t3e/

I am not sure if it works in IE11.

### Code

```css
.the-beginning {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.the-end {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container-outer {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 19999px;
  margin-top: -10000px;
}

.container > div {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
  background: white;
  order: 1;
}

.container > div:nth-child(odd) {
  order: -1;
}

.container > div:nth-child(1),
.container > div:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="the-beginning">THE BEGINNING</div>
<div class="container-outer">
  <div class="container">
    <div>LEFT 0</div>
    <div>RIGHT 0<br>RIGHT 0</div>
    <div>LEFT 1<br>LEFT 1<br>LEFT 1</div>
    <div>RIGHT 1</div>
    <div>LEFT 2</div>
    <div>RIGHT 2<br>RIGHT 2<br>RIGHT 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="the-end">THE END</div>
```

### Idea

Use `flex-direction: column;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` on the container, and `width: 50%;` on the items, as a first step towards showing the items in columns.

Use `order: -1;` and `order: 1` to sort odd and even elements into different columns.

Use a gratuitous `margin-top: 10000px;` on the first element of each column, and a `max-height: 19999px;` on the container, so that no two such items fit into one column. This will make sure each of these items starts in a new column. Compensate with a negative margin-top on the container. Cut it off with an outer container with `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: No. If you put a `style="height:400px;"`in your first (left) "item", everything else should have been placed right..

Comment: You are right. I did not read the question well enough. My answer solves a different problem. I will mention this in the answer.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if I got this right . .

> "the 2's should stand alone on the right side and the 1, 3's and 4
>   should stand on the left side (without space between them)."

**html:**

```
<div id="box">
    <div class="data">1</div>
    <div class="data" style="float:right">2<br/>2<br/>2<br/>2</div>
    <div class="data">3<br/>3</div>
    <div class="data">4</div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#box {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}
.data {
    height:auto;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ccc;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #000;
}
```

Fid:
http://jsfiddle.net/YdEW9/26/

This is pure css. Everything is `floated left` then gave inline-css to `float:right` on the div with `(4) 2's`

I kinda don't know how to set the inline-css without javascript. Server side maybe? but I doubt you can get the height of the elements.

Well anyway hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

PURE CSS SOLUTION:

Add the following to your css file:

```
ol.context li:nth-child(even) {
float: right;
}
```

DO NOT change your html or anything else.

Result in FF:

[image: Firefox rendering]

--

## How it Works

Instead of floating all your elements "left" and creating gaps, we float each container according to the side/column the element they reside in.

Comment: Doesn't work, as shown by this fiddle created by Ilya Streltsyn: http://jsfiddle.net/bMvPQ/9