# divs falling apart when text gets too long while they are beside and below each other

Tags: css, html, text

This css issue has been bugging me for awhile now, and I think it's time I see if anyone has found a fix for it yet. This usually occurs when I use a PHP do/while loop and inside it have divs that float left. There is a picture inside the div, and when the text gets too long, it does this. Where x is on the picture is an example of this. Anytime I have divs next to and below each other, the text tends to get just too long for the fellow divs. So I am wondering if there is a way short of using a text overflow to at least make them behave in a way that keeps the design from falling apart. The css is simple in this example:

```
width: 25%;
margin-left: 1%;
float: left;
padding-bottom: 3%;
```

Any ideas?

[image: example]

Comment: possible duplicate of [balanced alternating column layout in CSS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597956/balanced-alternating-column-layout-in-css3)

Comment: not really... relative, but not a suitable answer imo. Preferably i'd like to stay away from absolute positioning.

Comment: You were able to say that after 18 seconds? There is no css solution for this problem unless you define fixed columns. You might be lucky with isotope or masonry.

Comment: You can set `max-height` to avoid that. Or use table.

Comment: Hmmm, thank you, I'll check them out. I wonder if there is a way I could achieve this with PHP.

Comment: @Lolo in this case the text will overflow the container. He would need to use overflow: auto to make it work.

Comment: @Layne it will, this is compromise.
@micker If you set `width` to 25% why don't you use table? Column layout using float make sense if you have variable column count depending on browser window size. With `width` set on 25% you will always have 3 columns.